# Can a command/alias be variable?

Tags: shell, alias, bash

I need to view a specific line of a log file from time to time:

```
$ head -10 log.txt|tail -1  # to view line 10 of log.txt
```

Then I wrote a function `v` in my `bashrc` to make life easier:

```
$ v 10
```

Ok, maybe I'm a little splitting hair here: I'd like to ignore the space too:

```
$ v10
```

The only way I know is to define lots of alias:

```
alias v1='v 1'
alias v2='v 2'
alias v3='v 3'
alias v4='v 4'
...
```

Is there any good way for this?

---

Thanks @Chirlo and @anishsane for the idea.

Here is my final version, based on @anishsane's with some fixes:

```
eval "`declare -f command_not_found_handle | sed s/command_not_found_handle/command_not_found_handle_orig/`"
command_not_found_handle(){
    if expr match "$1" "v[0-9][0-9]*" >/dev/null ; then
       v ${1:1}
       return $?
    fi
    command_not_found_handle_orig "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a hint:

When you give some command on ubuntu, & if that program is not installed, then the shell calls its own handler, saying

```
The program 'something' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install something
```

You can try finding that piece of program, which does this. Then hook your code, which would look if command is matching regex `v[0-9]*` & then execute `v $lineNumber` based on some parsing of command...

---

Based on chepner's comment, here is the update:

Add below in your .bashrc:

```
eval "`declare -f command_not_found_handle | sed s/command_not_found_handle/command_not_found_handle_orig/`"

command_not_found_handle(){
    if expr match "$1" "v[0-9]*" >/dev/null ; then
       v ${1:1}
       return $?
    fi
    command_not_found_handle_orig "$@"
}
```

Comment: Ubuntu provides a default implementation of `bash`'s `command_not_found_handle` function, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [command_not_found_handle ()](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) if you have `bash` > 4, you can override it to handle this case. When you type `v10` and the bash can't resolve it, this function will be called with the `v10` as the first parameter, and you catch it and do your thing there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, sorry that I can't accept two answers, though I really like to.