# Override a shell function, keep a reference to the original one

Tags: shell, posix

Is it possible to override a shell function and keep a reference to the original one?

```
f()  { echo original; }
f()  { echo wrapper; ...; }
f
```

The output of this should be:

```
wrapper
original
```

Is this possible in a semi-portable way?

Rationale: I'm trying to test my program by replacing parts of it with shell functions which record their calls into a log file.  This works fine as long as I only wrap commands and builtins, and as long as I don't mind indiscriminate logging.  Now I'd like to make the test suite more maintainable by only recording the interesting piece in each test.

So let's say my program consists of

```
f
g
h
```

where `f`, `g`, `h` are all shell functions, and I'd like to trace the execution of just `g`.

Comment: what you want can be done, but not very portably.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by Jens is correct. Just adding below code for completeness.

You can simply use it as below:

```
eval "`declare -f f | sed '1s/.*/_&/'`" #backup old f to _f

f(){
    echo wrapper
    _f # pass "$@" to it if required.
}
```

I had used same logic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15758880/793796

Comment: +1. I also used this technique [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73262/how-do-i-teach-bash-in-ubuntu-some-curse-words/73282#73282)

Answer (score 7):

Many shells (zsh, ksh, bash at least) support `typeset -f f` to dump the contents of `f()`.
Use this to save the current definition to a file; then, define `f()` as you want. Restore f() by sourcing the file created with `typeset`.

If you slightly modify the dumped function (renaming `f()` to `_f()` on the first line; a bit trickier when f() is recursive or calls other functions you frobbed in the same way), you can likely get this to produce the output you desired.

Comment: Neither `typeset` nor `declare` are POSIX (Issue 8, 2013).

Comment: @Jens: You mean Issue 7 TC1 (2013 edition).  Issue 8 hasn't been issued yet.  :)